# node-schedule cron job rules

Tags: node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have created few `cron` format based upon my project requirements and not sure if they all are correct. I tested for minutes and hourly and they are working fine but not sure about the rest of the others. Hence sharing below so that I could be corrected if I am wrong in any place:

```
           case "yearly":
                interval = '0 0 0 1 1 *'; //start of the year, 1st of Jan every year
                break;
            case "monthly":
                interval = '0 0 0 1 * *'; //beginning of month, 1st of every month
                break;
            case "weekly":
                interval = '0 0 0 * * 7'; //every week on Sunday
                break;
            case "daily":
                interval = '0 0 * * *'; //every day at 12 AM
                break;
            case "hourly":
                interval = '0 0 1 * * *'; //every hour
                break;
            default:
                interval = '* * * * *'; //every minute
                break;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're referring to https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

```
*    *    *    *    *    *
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │    └ day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 is Sun)
│    │    │    │    └───── month (1 - 12)
│    │    │    └────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    │    └─────────────── hour (0 - 23)
│    └──────────────────── minute (0 - 59)
└───────────────────────── second (0 - 59, OPTIONAL)
```

hourly will only work one time a day at 1am 0mins 0sec

Comment: Then how to define this for every hour?

Comment: interval = '0 0 * * * *'; //every hour at 0 min 0 sec